# Cannot use base class for request in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am trying to pass a base request and then use the child request in the corresponding methods as shown below, but as the method signatures are not the same, it throws error :(

***Request:***

```
@Data
public class ExportRequest {

}


@Data
public class MenuExportRequest extends ExportRequest {
    private UUID menuUuid;
}
```

***Controller:***

```
private final MenuExporter menuExporter;

public void exportMenus(@PathVariable UUID menuUuid) {
        MenuExportRequest request = new MenuExportRequest();
        request.setMenuUuid(menuUuid);
        
        final MultipartFile multipartFile = menuExporter.export(request);
    }
```

***interface and abstract classes:***

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export(ExportRequest request) throws IOException;
}


public abstract class AbstractDataExporter<T> implements DataExporter {

    @Override
    public MultipartFile export(ExportRequest request) throws IOException {

        final Iterable<T> entities = getEntities(request);

        // code omitted 
    }

    protected abstract Iterable<T> getEntities(ExportRequest request); // < --- !!!
}
```

***implementation:***

```
public class MenuExporter extends AbstractDataExporter<MenuDTO> {


    @Override
    protected Iterable<MenuDTO> getEntities(MenuExportRequest request){ // < --- !!!
        UUID menuUuid = request.getMenuUuid();

        // code omitted
    }
}
```

There is a problem with method and gives "*Method does not override method from its superclass*" error as the method and its implementation have different signature. SO, how can I fix that problem and use parent request for all the implementation of `AbstractDataExporter`?

Comment: We could make `DataExporter` generic in `<T extends ExportRequest>` and then define `export(...)` as `MultipartFile export(T request) throws IOException;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems a good approach. But it did not make any sense despite I applied necessary steps to `DataExporter`. Should I make any change related to `getEntities()` method that has error?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know which changes in detail are necessary, but we would have to change more than only adding the generic parameter in this one class. For one, the  `AbstractDataExporter` most probably needs a 2nd generic parameter `U extends ExportRequest` that then should be used to typify `DataExporter<U>`.

Comment: Finally I fixed the problem by making some changes, **thanks a lot** for your helps. Just a question that I am not sure:  What is extends e.g. `<T extends ExportRequest>` in this generic? Does it mean that the accepted generic must be extended from `ExportRequest`?

Comment: They are called bounded types. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable helps, voted up. I read this document, but it is not clear as your explanations. So, could you please the real aim to use bounded types? I think to limit the data types, is that true?